# Javascript Formatting date not working

Tags: javascript

I am using the ionic framework and I am trying to calculate the number of days between today and Sun Apr 18 2017 15:14:36 GMT+0800 (MYT)

and today  :Thu Mar 09 2017 17:52:48 GMT+0800 (MYT)

it's showing that there are 44 days but I know it's 40 days. Can someone help me fix my code

`$scope.daysLeft=Math.floor(Math.abs(newDate - new Date())/86400000);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: how come it is 40 days? march-21 days left and april 23 days..

Comment: @MartinSchneider Im not sure what I'm doing wrong. And I did refer to that post but it's giving me the wrong day number.

Comment: `Math.round((new Date(2017,3,18)-new Date(2017, 2, 09))/(1000*60*60*24)) -> 40`, the linked method is correct

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong and the result is actually ok from your program.
There are 44 days between today and the selected date.

#### Just try [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?m1=3&d1=9&y1=2017&m2=04&d2=23&y2=2017) if you don't believe it.

Comment: sorry I entered the wrong date, I''ll update the question. But the date is between today and April 18th. Its showing me 44 days.

Comment: show us the console log..I think you entered the wrong date in code also..@noor

Comment: my console log produces this for new Date() :Thu Mar 09 2017 17:52:48 GMT+0800 (MYT) 

And this for the newDate variable: Tue Apr 18 2017 12:20:02 GMT+0800 (MYT)
jobListings.js:185

Comment: Edit your question don't add here the information requested.

Comment: I did fix the question